# External HDD connected to router. How to use it as Ubuntu home directory?

Tags: networking, hard-drive, external-hdd, router

I have a computer without USB, using Ubuntu (latest version). I have a router with a place to insert usb stick or external usb harddisk (to use it on the network). The computer is connected with this router.

This computer has a HDD of 8 GB (enough only for the operating system, software installations and cache).

Is there any option to use the external HDD (connected on router) as my home directory on this PC?

*I am a begginer of Ubuntu OS, but I am familiarized with terminal from a CentOS server. Thank you all for helping me!*